# Block LU factorization with more than two blocks?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices, lu-decomposition

If I have a symmetric, positive definite block matrix there [exists the following LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_LU_decomposition):

$$\left[\matrix{A && B^\intercal \\ B && C}\right]=\left[\matrix{A^{\frac{1}{2}} && 0 \\ BA^{-\frac{1}{2}} && Q^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right]\left[\matrix{A^{\frac{1}{2}} && A^{-\frac{1}{2}}(B^{\intercal})^{\frac{1}{2}} \\ 0 && Q^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right]$$

where $Q = C - BA^{-1}B^{\intercal}$. Is it possible to derive a similar expression if I have a matrix subdivided into more than two blocks per row or column, for example:

$$\left[\matrix{A && B^\intercal && D^\intercal \\ B && C && E^\intercal \\ D &&  E && F}\right]$$

If yes, what would a decomposition equivalent to the one above look like?